# Authentication using Google Github

Tags: authentication

I have created one simple app where I can login using Google and GitHub. Its working fine. I have
implemented using Next-Auth "google-Authentication-provider", GitHub-Authentication-provider  and using my client-id and client-secret. But i am not able to understand if I deploy this , will it work for everyone and how , because I am using my own client ID and Client secret. is it not only specific to me ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, the authentication will work for everyone, not just for you, because the client ID and client secret are used to identify your app, not an individual user. Ensure that you manage your credentials securely and configure the OAuth settings correctly on Google and GitHub tho.

Comment: okay thanks for the reply